# Create routing between non-VLAN router and HP 2848 Procurve

Tags: routing, switch, hp, hp-procurve

I am trying to create this routing but getting some issues(or not having the routing).

Scenario:
simple router: 192.168.1.254 (with DHCP server for all network that is providing wifi and internet to the network).

Internal network: 192.168.1.0/24

HPE 2848 Procurve: 192.168.1.250

Now I have some servers inside the network that uses 192.168.10.0(vlan 33) and 192.168.25.0(vlan 25)
Those subnets are configured on some ports of the Switch. All works ok as long I test inside the subnets/vlans. There are untagged.

But I would like that the subnet 192.168.1.0 could reach those 2 subnets.

I tried to create a routing in the HP with "ip route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254"
And also in the simple router created 3 routes:

```
192.168.1.0  255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
192.168.25.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
```

The goal is not to have internet using those vlans, but only to be able to connect between those subnets.

But is not working. So what I am missing here? Is this the right way to route these subnets/vlans?

**UPDATE:**
reset all HP Procurve configuration.
Problem with connecting Router / Switch fixed, a cable was doing a loop.

Changed Switch IP to 192.168.1.253 and using now vlan 10 and 25.

#### This is the configuration now

```
**ProCurve Switch 2848# show run**

Running configuration:

; J4904A Configuration Editor; Created on release #I.10.107
hostname "ProCurve Switch 2848"
ip routing
snmp-server community "public" Unrestricted

vlan 1
   name "Maintenance"
   untagged 1-6,8-12,14-17,19-32,35-38,40,43-48
   ip address 192.168.1.253 255.255.255.0
   no untagged 7,13,18,33-34,39,41-42
   exit

vlan 10
   name "VLAN10"
   untagged 7,18,34,42
   ip address 192.168.10.253 255.255.255.0
   jumbo
   exit

vlan 25
   name "VLAN25"
   untagged 13,33,39,41
   ip address 192.168.25.253 255.255.255.0
   jumbo
   exit
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.254
spanning-tree
ip ssh
password manager
```

```
ProCurve Switch 2848# sho ip route
                                                                                                                               IP Route Entries
  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
  0.0.0.0/0          192.168.1.254   1    static               1          1
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          250  
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            0          0  
  192.168.1.0/24     Maintenance     1    connected            0          0   
  192.168.10.0/24    VLAN10          10   connected            0          0   
  192.168.25.0/24    VLAN25          25   connected            0          0
```

```
ProCurve Switch 2848# show IP

 Internet (IP) Service  
  IP Routing : Enabled
 
  Default TTL     : 64
  Arp Age         : 20
  VLAN         | IP Config  IP Address      Subnet Mask     Proxy ARP 
  ------------ + ---------- --------------- --------------- ---------   
  Maintenance  | Manual     192.168.1.253   255.255.255.0   No
  VLAN10       | Manual     192.168.10.253  255.255.255.0   No
  VLAN25       | Manual     192.168.25.253  255.255.255.0   No
```

On the Router side I disable the route: 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.254 gateway 192.168.1.253

Comment: You'll need to add an IP address to the 2848 on all VLANs, enable routing (`ip routing`) and then add routes for the remote subnets on the Fritzbox - however, home networking and consumer-grade hardware are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. You might want to try on [su].

Comment: dont understand why is off-topic and why this is mark as home networking. Because using a Fritzbox?

this is HP Procurve  2848
4x HP Dl360 G9 servers
ESXi vSphere 7 
and a QNAP with 40Tb.

If this is home networking, I would like to have one.
But ok, I will open in the other area.

Comment: The AVM Fritzbox is a consumer-grade product, making it off-topic here. Also, the 2800 series is quite ancient (EoS 2009), so I assumed a home network. If you leave the Fritzbox out of your question and it's about an on-topic business network, then we could reopen it. I have edited the question accordingly, **please add the 2848's config (using the editor's `{ }` function for readability), so we can see what's wrong.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've added IP addresses to the additional VLANs on the switch, these are used as default gateway for the attached end nodes, e.g.:

```
vlan 33 ip address 192.168.10.253/24
vlan 25 ip address 192.168.25.253/24
```

Add a default route to the switch - there's no need to add other routes if all networks are attached to the switch:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.1.254
```

Turn on routing on the switch:

```
ip routing
```

You've already added the subnets behind the switch to your router (you need to point them to the L3 switch though). Instead of adding each subnet seperately you could just use a summary route

```
192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.253
```

unless there are other routers for the internal network.

Don't forget to change the 192.168.1.0/24 nodes' default gateway to 192.168.1.253 (all nodes but the L3 switch). Alternatively, you could leave the router as default gateway and add explicit routes for 192.168.25.0/24 and 192.168.33.0/24 (or the summary 192.168.0.0/16) via 192.168.1.253 - just like on the router).

Now all VLANs should be routed in between and towards the Internet. To prevent the latter you could use an ACL on the appropriate ports (I think the 2848 doesn't support VLAN ACLs yet), something along:

```
ip access-list extended LANonly
   1000 permit ip 192.168.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/16
   1010 permit ip 192.168.1.0/24 any          
exit
interface 25 ip access-group LANonly in
```

(There's an implicit `deny ip any any` at the end of each ACL.)

DHCP won't work with your router for the subnets behind the L3 switch. The router would need to support VLANs (with direct subnet attachment) or DHCP relay via helper configuration on the switch.

Comment: That is what I did before. But was using instead 192.168.x.2 for both vlans. 
IP routing I also enabled.

So if I understand, is:

vlan 33 ip address 192.168.10.250
vlan 25 ip address 192.168.25.250

ip route 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.1.254
IP routing (already enabled)

and on the router create a routing 
192.168.0.0/16 gateway 192.168.1.250

I still have in the router the routing: 192.168.1.0/24 gateway 192.168.1.254. Do I need to delete?
If yes, a question, will this not impact the DHCP and the other clients on the subnet 192.168.1.x

Comment: Possibly the only problem with your setup was the routes on the router pointing to the router itself as gateway, which needs to the L3 switch instead. 192.168.1.0/24 is directly attached, so it requires no explicit route at all.

Comment: I reset HP Switch configuration and start over. 
This is the new configuration.

ProCurve Switch 2848# show  ip

 Internet (IP) Service

  IP Routing : Enabled


  Default TTL     : 64
  Arp Age         : 20

  VLAN         | IP Config  IP Address      Subnet Mask     Proxy ARP
  ------------ + ---------- --------------- --------------- ---------
  DEFAULT_VLAN | Manual     192.168.1.250   255.255.255.0   Yes
  VLAN25       | Manual     192.168.25.250  255.255.255.0   No
  VLAN33       | Manual     192.168.10.250  255.255.255.0   No

Comment: ProCurve Switch 2848# show ip route
                                IP Route Entries
  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
  0.0.0.0/0          192.168.1.254   1    static               1          1
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          250
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            0          0
  192.168.1.0/24     DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            0          0

Comment: And in the router I add the route: 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.254 gateway 192.168.1.250

But when I connect a cable from Switch to router, router lost connection and can't ping the router itself that is the 192.168.1.254

Comment: Please add/update the config in your question - it's barely readable as comment. `0.0.0.0 255.255.255.254 gateway 192.168.1.250` on the router serves absolutely no purpose.

Comment: You are right comment is not very good. Updated the original question.

Comment: Looks OK - on the router you still need either separate routes for 192.168.33.0/24 and 192.168.25.0/24 via 192.168.1.253, or an aggregate/universal route for 192.168.0.0/16. If there's still a problem, ping and traceroute every which way and tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: you mean adding the same routes on the router?
like 192.168.25.0/24 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.253 and 192.168.10.0/24 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.253

Comment: Yes, either that or the summary route. Since you don't want those subnet to access the Internet anyway, you could omit those routes. Check out the note in my answer to change the default gateway for 192.168.1.0/24 end nodes.

Comment: yes, the only subnet that will access internet is 192.168.1.x, which is the management network.

Monday I will add those routes in the router and update the information here.
Thanks for all the help until now.

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes this did the trick
a final question, maybe I will have 2/3 devices that uses the vlan 10 that need internet for updates. Using 192.168.10.253 gateway they don't have internet. Do I need any extra routes for internet?
Thank you for the support

Comment: If any host on that VLAN requires Internet connectivity, a route on the router is required - the hosts use the layer-3 switch as default gateway and the router uses a route as the ones above. If not all devices should gain Internet access then you'll need a filter - either confguration on the router or an ACL on the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two vlan interfaces on the HPE for vlan 33 and vlan 25 with ip addresses belonging to those vlans, say `192.168.10.254` and `192.168.25.254`.

Hosts on those vlans must have their default gateway `192.168.10.254` and `192.168.25.254` respectively.

On HPE add a default route to `192.168.1.254`

On the Internet Router add routes for `192.168.10.0/24` and `192.168.25.0/24` pointing to `192.168.1.250`

I don't know for HPE, but probably you have to enable ip routing if it's not enabled by default.

**UPDATE**

If you want hosts on `192.168.1.0/24` to be able to reach hosts on `vlan33` and `vlan25`, make sure that the default gateway for hosts on `192.168.1.0/24` is `192.168.1.253`.

Now you'll have reachability between vlans and only `vlan1` can get to the Internet as only `192.168.1.0/24` is NATed by the router